# What happens when std::move is called on a rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Consider the following c++ programs:

```
string construct(string&& s) {
    // Passing a r-value reference as an argument to the assignment operator
    string constructed = s;
    return constructed;
}

int main() {
    string original = "Hello";
    string temp1 = construct(std::move(original));

    printf("%s\n", original.c_str()); // Prints "Hello", so original has not changed
    return 0;
}
```

Now a small change that I perform is calling std::move on an r-value reference argument:

```
string constructWithMove(string&& s) {
    // Passing a cast to an r-value reference using r-value reference as an argument.
    string constructed = std::move(s);
    return constructed;
}

int main() {
    string original = "Hello";
    string temp = constructWithMove(std::move(original));

    printf("%s\n", original.c_str()); // Prints "", original is set to the empty string, WHY???
    return 0;
}
```

So it looks like casting an r-value reference to an r-value reference induces something peculiar. **Why in the first case the original string retains its value but not in the second**?

Comment: _Now a small change that I perform is calling std::move on an r-value reference argument_  No, that's not what you did.  You called std::move on an l-value reference parameter.

Comment: @Eljay Is `string&&` not an rvalue reference?

Comment: The parameter takes an r-value argument by reference.  The local parameter is named, so it is not an r-value, and needs to be `std::move`d to be used as a r-value.

Comment: I think point you're missing is that after `string constructed = s;`, `s` *must* remain valid and *cannot* be moved from. After all, the very next line of code could be `string constructed2 = s;`. However, in `string constructed = std::move(s);`, you have given permission to move from `s` to construct the new string and thus it may change `s` to a valid but different state.

Comment: @eerorika Perhaps that should have been rephrased: you cannot call functions on arguments of reference type *because there is no such thing as an expression of reference type*. In `constructWithMove`, the expression `s` is an lvalue of type `string`. `std::move` is being called with an lvalue `string`. The declaration `string &&s` influence what *binds to `s`* (at the callsite) but does not affect the behavior of `s` within the function body. Actually calling `std::move` on an rvalue would be `std::move(std::move(s))` or something like `std::move(std::string(""))`.

Comment: @Eljay So if the local parameter is an l-value reference, then why calling `construct(original)` where `string original& = "Hello"` gives a compile time error? In this case `original` is an `l-value reference` as well. So why can't I pass `original` as an argument, but `std::move(original)` as an argument is allowed and inside the function the passed argument is an l-value reference? What am I confusing here?

Comment: @mercury0114 As I said: the way that you declare `s` in the signature of `construct` controls *how you can call it*, but inside the body of `construct` `s` is always an lvalue. If you declare `std::string &&s`, then you can only call `construct` on rvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string constructed = s;
```

This does not cause a move because `s` is *not an rvalue*. It is an rvalue reference, but not an rvalue. If it has a name, it is not an rvalue. [Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

```
string constructed = std::move(s);
```

This causes a move because `std::move(s)` is an rvalue: it's a temporary and its type is not lvalue reference.

There are no other moves in the program (`std::move` is *not* a move, it's a cast).

Comment: Is `std::move(s)` an rvalue or **rvalue-reference**? I thought `std::move` makes a cast to r-value-reference, no?

Comment: @mercury0114 it is an rvalue because it is a temporary. Its type is "rvalue reference to string". The two properties are orthogonal.

Answer (score 7):

> What happens when std::move is called on a rvalue reference?

`std::move` casts the argument into an rvalue reference, which it returns.

> Is `std::move(r_value_reference_argument)` undefined

No.

---

> ```
> // Prints "", original is set to the empty string, WHY???
> ```
>
> What's happening here?

Because the result from `std::move` is an r-value (x-value to be more specific). And being passed to a constructor of `std::string`, it invokes the move constructor. You are observing a string that was moved from.

Note that this moving leaves the original string in an unspecified state. It is not guaranteed to be empty, nor even different from what it used to contain. Neither is it guaranteed to not be empty.

---

> OK, but why in the first case the original string is not empty?

Because `s` is an lvalue<sup>1</sup>, and therefore the copy constructor was used. The copy constructor leaves the original string unmodified.

<sup>1</sup> Easy rule of thumb: If it is a name, then it is an l-value.

Comment: OK, but why in the first case the original string is not empty? I modified the question a bit.

Comment: @mercury0114, `s` is an lvalue. Its type is irrelevant.

Comment: @mercury0114: because of that, `string constructed = s;` invokes copy-construction.  The compiler won't move from it unless you explicitly use `std::move`, as a later line in the function might also refer to `s` and expect it to still be in the state passed as a function argument.  Using `std::move()` is effectively promising the compiler you understand that and have coded accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`// Prints "", original is set to the empty string, WHY???`

Because you moved it.

Comment: To be precise, having been moved-from explains why it's *allowed* to empty, but doesn't require it to be so.  The general expectation of a moved-from value is that it will be left in a valid state for destruction.  I personally think it's desirable to design your own movable types so they'll be valid for reassignment or `clear()` then reuse, but this is a quality-of-implementation matter.  For types that don't document semantics for moved-from objects, you should only depend on "destructability" and not assume or depend on the moved-from object having any particular value or being reusable.

Comment: (In particular, some objects with pointers to dynamically allocated memory may swap buffers, so any text in the destination object ends up in the moved-from object, as a lazy way to provide the moved-from object with some heap-allocated memory in case it is reused, and defer deallocation).

Comment: How about throwing an exception?

Comment: `if (ive_been_moved) throw std::logic_error("hammer error: can't touch this");`

Comment: @super: you *never* want a destructor to throw an exception, so if there's something in the move-then-destruct processing that might throw, you definitely want that done at "move time".  Elijay's allusion to objects tracking/checking for moved-from state is rarely desirable: just a whole new surface of extra state/logic that can go wrong; when possible, just put the object back in a "normal" state where the expected operations will work or throw or whatever of their own accord.